# Maximum number of products for given amount from the product list in SQL server without using While/Cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table named '**Product**'

```
Create table products(ProductName VARCHAR(100), Price INT, Quantity INT)

Insert into products values ('Pencil',3,20)
Insert into products values ('Rubber',4,5)
Insert into products values ('Scale',15,4)

ProductName  Price       Quantity
------------------------ -----------
Pencil       3           20
Rubber       4           5
Scale        4           15
```

**Here is the requirement.**

What is the maximum number of items that can be bought by spending at most $100?

I just need the output value as **26**. (*20 Pencils + 5 Rubbers + 1 Scale*)

I don't want the list of items, I just need the maximum possible products.

If the table only have the below values

```
ProductName  Price       Quantity
------------ ----------- -----------
Book         90          2
Note         120         4
```

I just need to return **1**(*Can't buy any more products than 1 book*)

This needs to achieve in `T-SQL`. We are not allowed to use `WHILE` or `CURSOR`.

Comment: Do you at least have an algorithm you want to implement? Have you looked at a recursive common table expression (CTE)?

Comment: SQL Server <> SQLite, and SQLite doesn't use T-SQL; what are you actually using here?

Comment: This problem doesn't really make sense as a problem to solve with T-SQL either, if I am honest.

Comment: If you choose to buy 20 Pencils + 1 Rubbers + 9 Scale = 30 items, would you choose your 26 or the 30 items

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the conflicting tags for now, as the OP hasn't clarified what they are using. They will need to [edit] their question to (re)add the appropriate tag(s).

Comment: @Dordi - Sorry my bad. Instead of 15, I put the price as 4. Now I updated the question

Comment: Hi @Larnu / Hello all - This question asked to me in an Interview. They want me to do it in SQL server scripts without using While and Cursor.

Comment: Well, it's that the case, *you* should be answered this, not us; we aren't doing the interview, ***you*** are.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's to be asking for interview help. Although not "homework", such questions should still include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Us answering your interview question(s) will not help you or others; especially if you end up getting a role you are unsuited for as the answer you provided isn't your own.

Comment: Hi @Larnu, I'm not selected for that role. I tried my best in google but I'm not getting anything,  and I want to learn it. That's why I raised this here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive common table expression (CTE) to create every possible case, a query would be like that:

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(max) = ';WITH cte as (
    SELECT ProductName,Price,1 AS Qte
    FROM #products
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cte.ProductName,cte.Price,Qte + 1
    FROM cte
    JOIN #products p ON p.ProductName = cte.ProductName
    WHERE cte.Qte < p.Quantity
)
SELECT MAX(c1.Price * c1.Qte + c2.Price * c2.Qte + c3.Price * c3.Qte), MAX(c1.Qte + c2.Qte + c3.Qte) 
FROM cte c1'

;with cte as 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ProductName) AS NB_CONDITION, 1 AS increment
    FROM #products

    UNION ALL

    SELECT p.*,c.NB_CONDITION,increment + 1
    FROM cte c
    JOIN #products p ON c.ProductName = p.ProductName 
    WHERE c.increment < NB_CONDITION
)

SELECT @Query = @Query + CONCAT(' INNER JOIN cte c', NB_CONDITION, ' ON ', STRING_AGG(CONCAT('c' ,NB_CONDITION ,'.ProductName <> c', increment , '.ProductName'), ' AND '))
FROM cte
WHERE NB_CONDITION <> increment
GROUP BY NB_CONDITION

SET @Query = @Query + ' WHERE c1.Price * c1.Qte + c2.Price * c2.Qte + c3.Price * c3.Qte <= 100'

PRINT (@Query)

exec (@Query)
```

I used dynamic SQL to create the joints to ensure different combinations.

Comment: Is there any possibilities, without using Dynamic SQL?

Comment: Yes you can, if know how much product you have in advance, but i think that's not the case.

Comment: That is not fixed, that may vary.